# How to auto import Python functions in VIM?

Tags: python, plugin-python-mode

Let's say I need `reverse` function in my newly created `hello_world.py` file and I have not imported it yet:

```
url = reverse('hell-world')
```

I would love to go onto the `reverse` name, press VIM binding and get `from django.urls import reverse` line inserted in the beginning of the file, e.g.:

```
from django.urls import reverse

url = reverse('hello-world')
```

I have heard about `ropevim`, `python-mode` VIM plugins, however I have not managed to make them work as I described above.

Comment: What if another module implements a `reverse` function as well? Or you want to limit yourself to django?

Comment: A list of import options should be provided to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function for that (easier with python [`:h if_pyth`](https://vimways.org/2018/a-python-interface-cookbook/)).

```python
# intial setup
import inspect`
potential_modules = ['django', 'sys', 'os']
for module_name in potential_modules:
    exec(f"from {module_name} import *")
```

```python
def add_import_on_trigger()
    func_name = get_the_word_under_cursor();
    module_name = inspect.getmodule(func_name)
    import_statement = f"from {module_name} import {func_name}"
    add_import_statement_at_the_buffer_top()
```

Comment: word under cursor will be `expand('<cword>')`. Can use `vim.eval()`. Adding the import statement in the right spot is harder, but something like `execute '$?^import\|^from? put ='.import_statement` might do it